# Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3} +i$ over $Q(i)$ and over $Q(\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Find the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{3} +i$ over $Q(i)$ and $Q(\sqrt{3})$.

My solution:

- Over $Q(i)$ : Suppose $a = \sqrt{3} +i$, $a-\sqrt{3} =i$;
  so, the minimal polynomial is $x-\sqrt{3} -i=0$.
- Over $Q(\sqrt{3})$:  Suppose a=$\sqrt{3} +i$, $a-\sqrt{3} =i$; by squaring both side of this equation, $a^2-2\sqrt{3}a+3=-1$. So, we get $x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+4=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{3} \not\in \Bbb Q(i)$, its minimal polynomial over that field cannot be linear.

Comment: @Travis over the Q(i) ; the answer should be $p(x)=x^2-2xi-4$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get, too.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Consider the product of the monomial $$x - (\sqrt{3} + i)$$ with its conjugate, in two different senses of the word conjugate. (One of the products recovers the correct partial solution from the question: The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3} + i$ over $\Bbb Q (\sqrt{3})$ is $x^2 - 2\sqrt{3} x + 4 = 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another approach: What’s the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3$ over $\Bbb Q(i)$? Certainly $X^2-3$. But if $\lambda\in\Bbb Q(i)$, then the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3+\lambda$ over that field is surely $(X-\lambda)^2-3$, don’t you agree? Use this principle on your two cases, and you will get the right answer(s).